# Choose an early and nearest date from same group in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I would like to get an early and nearest date from others in the same group (region) using postgresql.

```
    +----+--------+------------+
    | id | region |    date1   |
    +----+--------+------------+
    |  1 | a      | 2017-01-01 |
    |  2 | a      | 2017-01-07 |
    |  3 | a      | 2017-03-03 |
    |  4 | a      | 2017-04-03 |
    |  5 | b      | 2017-02-02 |
    |  6 | b      | 2017-02-28 |
    +----+--------+------------+
```

I aggregated and got a below table but lost the next step.

```
SELECT string_agg(id, ';') AS ids, region, 
STRING_AGG(to_char(date1, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),';') AS dates
FROM table1
GROUP BY region

+---------+--------+---------------------------------------------+
|   ids   | region |                    dates                    |
+---------+--------+---------------------------------------------+
| 1;2;3;4 | a      | 2017-01-01;2017-01-07;2017-03-03;2017-04-03 |
| 5;6     | b      | 2017-02-02;2017-02-28                       |
+---------+--------+---------------------------------------------+
```

Here I am not sure how to construct the following table.

```
+----+--------+------------+----------------+
| id | region |   date1    | neareast_early |
+----+--------+------------+----------------+
|  1 | a      | 2017-01-01 |                |
|  2 | a      | 2017-01-07 | 2017-01-01     |
|  3 | a      | 2017-03-03 | 2017-01-07     |
|  4 | a      | 2017-04-03 | 2017-03-03     |
|  5 | b      | 2017-02-02 |                |
|  6 | b      | 2017-02-28 | 2017-02-02     |
+----+--------+------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it something like this:

```
SELECT a.*, IFNULL((SELECT b.date1 FROM table1 b WHERE b.date1 < a.date1 AND a.region = b.region ORDER BY b.date1 DESC LIMIT 1), "") AS neareast_early FROM table1 a;
```

Working [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ad7be/5)

Answer (score 0):

Use `LAG`

```
SELECT id
    ,region
    ,date1
    ,LAG(date1) OVER (
        PARTITION BY REGION ORDER BY ID
        ) AS neareast_early
FROM table1;
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/eb835/1)